# Making a switch statement in C with an array?

Tags: c, arrays, switch-statement

I am trying to make a switch statement that takes in a word into an array and then throws each letter through a switch statement and allocates a point to each letter depending on which letter it is and giving a final point value for the word, and I can't seem to get the array part right. Any help would be appreciated!

```
int main(){
int letter_points = 0;
char word[7];
int word_length = 7;
int i;
printf("Enter a Word\n");
scanf("%s", word);
for(i = 0; i < word_length; i++){

switch(word){
    //1 point
    case 'A':
    case 'E':
    case 'I':
    case 'L':
    case 'N':
    case 'O':
    case 'R':
    case 'S':
    case 'T':
    case 'U':
        letter_points++;
        break;
    //2 points
    case 'D':
    case 'G':
        letter_points += 2;
        break;
    //3 points
    case 'B':
    case 'C':
    case 'M':
    case 'P':
        letter_points += 3;
        break;
    //4 points
    case 'F':
    case 'H':
    case 'V':
    case 'W':
    case 'Y':
        letter_points += 4;
        break;
    //5 points
    case 'K':
        letter_points += 5;
        break;
    //8 points
    case 'J':
    case 'X':
        letter_points += 8;
        break;
    //10 points
    case 'Q':
    case 'Z':
        letter_points += 10;
        break;
}
}
printf("%d\n", letter_points);
return;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, your word array can hold a maximum of **6** letters plus a terminating null. There's nothing to keep a user from entering 7 or more letters and getting a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this

```
 switch(word[i]){
```

in the switch statement. As it stands, you are not testing each element in your array even though you are iterating over the range of the array. Having said that I would go for the approach suggested by Kerrek SB in the other answer. This is much neater and more compact.

Answer (score 7):

It would probably be faster to have a lookup array:

```
int const letter_score[26] = { 1, 2, 1, 3, ..., 10 };
/*                      key:   A  B  C  D        Z    */

score += letter_score[c - 'A'];   // or "toupper(word[i]) - 'A'"
```

Caveat: this requires an encoding in which the upper-case letters are arranged contiguously, such as Unicode or ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `word` is an array, but you want to `switch` on each character. Thus, you need:

```
switch(word[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, you cannot use arrays in `switch` (and expressions for `case`). Also, the type passed to `switch()` and types specified in each `case` must match. So the most you can do is switch on a character. You almost got it right though, except that you are passing the whole array into switch. Use index to reference a character instead. For example:

```
switch (word[i]) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have word as an array of size7, you cannot switch on the array, you have to swicth on each character of the array so use:
switch(word[i])