# Scrabble Point Counter

Tags: c

I am working on a scrabble program that generates 7 letters, then allows the user to enter words and see if they are valid and what the point value would be. As soon as I started doing the values is when I started having problems.

I am calling the function wordvalue like this, and wanting to store the result into value.
The users word is stored into userword[8].

```
int value = wordvalue(userword[8]);
```

Here is my code to figure out what letter is in the array cell, then add. I am not sure what is wrong with it but it crashes every time at this step.

```
int wordvalue (char userword[8]){

    int m;
    int currentvalue = 0;

    for (m=0; m < 8; m++){

        switch (userword[m]){

        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'L':
        case 'N':
        case 'O':
        case 'R':
        case 'S':
        case 'T':
        case 'U':
            currentvalue = currentvalue + 1;
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'G':
            currentvalue = currentvalue + 2;
            break;
        case 'B':
        case 'C':
        case 'M':
        case 'P':
            currentvalue = currentvalue + 3;
            break;
        case 'F':
        case 'H':
        case 'V':
        case 'W':
        case 'Y':
            currentvalue = currentvalue + 4;
            break;
        case 'K':
            currentvalue = currentvalue + 5;
            break;
        case 'J':
        case 'X':
            currentvalue = currentvalue + 8;
            break;
        case 'Q':
        case 'Z':
            currentvalue = currentvalue + 10;
            break;

        }


    }

    //printf("%d", currentvalue);
    return currentvalue;
}
```

Comment: You should cooperate with Eric :-). (http://stackoverflow.com/q/12427641/1310220)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int value = wordvalue(userword[8]);
```

This call looks wrong.

Assuming `userword` is an array of `char` you are passing a `char` where a pointer to `char` is expected.

You probably wanted to do:

```
int value = wordvalue(userword);
```

Comment: can he use address of 8th element to get other elements adress in the function?

Comment: Ah wow how could I have missed that. Thank you. It doesn't crash anymore but it doesn't seem like its returning currentvalue into value

Comment: @Ryan how can you know that it is not putting the value?

Comment: When i try and print out "value" after it returns from the function back to main it prints out some very large number when it should be printing 5, testing the word CAT

Comment: @Ryan Your code is written to always read `8` characters. CAT is not 8 characters.

Comment: Ah I understand. Will fix with the length of the string

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık not sufficient, he didn't say `userword` is a string and even if it was `CAT\0` is not the same as `CAT\0\0\0\0\0`

Comment: So would `for (m=0; m < strlen(userword) ; m++)` for the loop work or is there a different way?

Comment: @Ryan assuming `userword` is a string it is OK. Compute `strlen` at the top of your function only once is better.

Comment: Well it seems that its determining the string length correctly, but it is still returning a large number instead of 5 for "CAT" If i print out the number before leaving the function it prints 5, if I print it out after it prints 2676576

Comment: Just figured that part out. Thank you all for the help

Comment: @ouah Most compilers will only evaluate the condition in the loop one time because strlen(a) won't change in the loop. So you don't in this case need to compute strlen(a) and assign to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but I wanted to show you a way to avoid having to write that lengthy `switch` statement.

The `values[]` array contains the Scrabble value for each letter in the alphabet. The `letterValue()` function then uses the ASCII value of the letter - 'A' to index into the `values[]` array to get the letter value. `values[0] is for 'A'` and `values[25] is for 'Z'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* prototypes */
int wordvalue (char *userword);
int letterValue( char letter );

int values[] = { 1,3,3,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1,1,3,10,1,1,1,1,4,4,8,4,10 };

int letterValue( char letter )
{
    return( values[toupper((int)letter) - 'A'] );  
} 

int wordvalue(char *userword)
{
    int m;
    int currentvalue = 0;

    for (m=0; m < strlen(userword); m++)
    {
        currentvalue += letterValue( userword[m]);
    }
    return currentvalue;
}

int main()
{
    char word[] = "Progress";

    printf("Value of %s is %d\n", word, wordvalue(word));
    return( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `userword` is an already initialized string you must pass it to your function like this: `wordvalue(userword)`.

What you have is `int value = wordvalue(char userword[8])`.

One problem I see with this is that you are declaring `userword` which is an array of 8 characters inside your function argument.

By doing this you are actually passing the 8th element of `userword` to `wordvalue`. 
Since you just initialized this array the value of `userword[8]` is unknown, and your program is going to exhibit undefined behavior.

You need to initialize your array, and give it value:

```
int wordvalue(char *userword);         //function declaration

int main(void)
{
    char userword[8] = "foobarrr";         //declare 8 char array holding an 8 character string
    int value = wordvalue(userword);       //call the function
    printf("%d", value);                   //print function output
    return 0;
}

/*function prototype here*/
```